# Validation rule for laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I have a table GateAccess: id, person_id, gate_id, time_id.
When adding a new record to this table I'd like to prevent adding several records with the same gate_id for one person_id. Gate_id must be unique for particular person_id.

I'd like to have table like this:

```
id, person_id, gate_id, time_id
1, 2, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2
```

but not the one:

```
id, person_id, gate_id, time_id
1, 2, 1, 1
2, 2, 1, 2
```

I have a validator:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
        ], $messages);
```

Can you help me to make rule for this validator?

Comment: In addition to validation, consider a unique key at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `validator rule` to achieve what you want, so in your case your validation should look like this.

```
Validator::make($data, [
      'gate_id' => [
          'required',
          Rule::unique('GateAccess')->where(function ($query) use($data){
               $query->where('person_id', $data->person_id);
          })->ignore($request->id),
      ],
])->validate();
```

It will set the gate_id as unique where the person id in your record is equal to the person id you passed.

don't forget to add this above in your code

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need specify when you unique validation rules applied.
With laravel validator in like this:

```
[
  'some_field'=>'unique:table,field,NULL,id,criteria,compare'
]
```

That rule says that "some_field" will by unique when "criteria" are equal to "compare"

For you example is like this

```
$person_id = Request::get('person_id');
$gate_id = Request::get('gate_id');  

[
    'person_id' => 'unique:GateAccess,person_id,NULL,id,gate_id,' . $gate_id;
    'gate_id' => 'unique:GateAccess,gate_id,NULL,id,person_id,' . $person_id;
];
```

So person_id will by unique when gate_id are equal to $gate_id and the same way for gate_id